# Scrolling window within another page in selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to scroll a page within another page. see attached picture

[image]

I tried with the follwoing code

```
  JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

  js1.executeScript("","window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
```

But its scrolling the whole page instead of the window inside the page.
How do i specify that i want to scroll this certain window

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like, that is a window so try to switch to that window first then do the scroll down...

Comment: `window` will scroll the whole window. If you want to scroll in your popup, you have to find the element which is scrollable (e.g, div element) and then you can call your scroll function on that element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. This works for most of the scrolling case:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_Of_Element"));                 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
```